# Angular Increase Decrease Number count based on Id in an Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

In this case i want to achive dynamic increase decrease no count in an array.. I have a product list where i have to icrease or decrease the count before adding the item to cart

here is the HTML

```
<div class="add-prdct">
   <p (click) = "removeItem(item.id); 'pid = item.id' ">-</p>
   <span *ngIf="item.id === pid && isclicked === true">{{ itemCount }}</span>
   <span *ngIf="isclicked === false">1</span>
   <p (click) = "addItem(item.id); 'pid = item.id'">+</p>
</div>
```

Here item coming From the `ngFor Loop`

TS

```
addItem(id: any, index: any): void {
    this.itemCount++;
    this.pid = id;
    this.isclicked = true;
    // this.itemCount = this.itemCount + 1;
  }

  removeItem(id: any, index: any): void {
    this.pid = id;
    if (this.itemCount === 1) {
      this.itemCount = 1;
    } else {
      this.itemCount--;
    }
  }
```

And `itemCount = 1` initialized

The Problem is when i am increasing in a product the in other product the `{{ itemCount }}` its not holding the 1 value

Help

[image: demo]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what your code is doing from the excerpts that you are sharing. Please share the full template and code. From what you share it appears that the same `itemCount` is shared between all the items. But I may be wrong because not all your code is here.

Comment: yes bro `itemCount` is initialized as 1 for first time

Comment: But you want to hold items per product..?

Comment: i want to increase the the itemCount for that particular item and for others i want to keep it as 1

Comment: So don't share the same `itemCount` between all items. Keep count per item.

Comment: How to achieve that ??

Comment: @void maybe my answer below will help

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing the same `itemCount` between all your items. You need to have a count per item. You can use `Map` to achieve it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="add-prdct">
   <p (click) = "removeItem(item.id); 'pid = item.id' ">-</p>
   <span *ngIf="item.id === pid && isclicked === true">{{ itemsCountMap.get(item.id) }}</span>
   <span *ngIf="isclicked === false">1</span>
   <p (click) = "addItem(item.id); 'pid = item.id'">+</p>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
const itemsCountMap = new Map<any, number>();

// when initializing an item with id:
  this.itemsCountMap.set(id, 1);

// when incrementing
  addItem(id: any, index: any): void {
    const currentCount = this.itemsCountMap.get(id);

    this.itemsCountMap.set(id, currentCount + 1);
    this.pid = id;
    this.isclicked = true;
  }

// when decrementing
  removeItem(id: any, index: any): void {
    const currentCount = this.itemsCountMap.get(id);

    this.pid = id;
    if (currentCount > 0) {
      this.itemsCountMap.set(id, currentCount - 1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Please.

```
addItem()
  this.itemCount+1; instead this.itemCount++;


removeItem()
  this.itemCount-1; instead this.itemCount--;
```